# SDL.dll in the same directory of the .EXE

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, sdl

When I followed some tutorials of how to compile SDL2 with VSCODE they say copy the SDl.dll to the directory of the .exe??

May I ask Why ??

Comment: SDL.dll contains the code for (at least most of) the SDL library. Without it, your program that uses SDL won't be able to run.

Comment: thanks for the reply, (I am very new to programming in general) but why libraries like raylib i don't have to do that (with Vscode at least)

Comment: There are two kinds of libraries. A "static" library is one that's basically just a collection of pieces of code. When you use it, the pieces of code you used get copied into your program's executable, and you don' t need the library afterward. A "dynamic" library holds those pieces of code in a separate file, and your program uses them from that file.

Comment: if I correctly understand libraries such as Raylib uses static library and SDL uses dynamic(dll) , Right ?

Comment: Sounds like it anyway, yes.